# C++ Error in my own stack class

Tags: c++, exception, stack

This is a program with my Stack class:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    template <class T>
    struct Node{
        T element;
        Node<T> *prevElement;
    };

    template <class T>
    class Stack {
    private:
        unsigned int NumberOfElements;
        Node<T> *tempAdr;
        Node<T> *topElement;
    public:
        Stack(){
            topElement = new Node<T>;
            topElement->prevElement = nullptr;
            NumberOfElements = 0;
        }
        ~Stack(){
            delete topElement;
        }

        void push(T input_element){
            tempAdr = topElement->prevElement;
            topElement = new Node<T>;
            topElement->element = input_element;
            topElement->prevElement = tempAdr;
            NumberOfElements++;
        }

        void pop(){
            tempAdr = topElement->prevElement;
            delete topElement;
            topElement = tempAdr;
            NumberOfElements--;
        }

        T top(){
            return topElement->element;
        }

        unsigned int size(){
            return NumberOfElements;
        }

    };

    int main(){
        Stack<int> MyStack;
        MyStack.push(17);
        MyStack.push(18);
        MyStack.pop();
        cout << MyStack.top()<<" "<<MyStack.size();
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Expected output is

> 17 1

But when I run the code, I'm getting the error message:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00EE5FA9 in LB_4_RealStack.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

So, can you guys help me to find the error? I was looking through my code over and over again, but I didn't find the reason for the exception.

Comment: You didn't mention which line throws the exception.

Comment: @user2079303 `return topElement->element;` in my top() method

Comment: You should add that information to the question.

Comment: The error message clearly states that you are dereferencing a null pointer. Step through your code line by line, operation by operation, and determine where it diverges from the algorithm that you wrote out on paper before beginning.

Comment: Yeah, really. Thanks for attension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is in your push() method, the first instruction.

In fact what you obtain in the code is to add the element on top of the next element from the top (disregarding the current top), so if you rewrite the method as in:

```
void push(T input_element){
    tempAdr = topElement;
    topElement = new Node<T>;
    topElement->element = input_element;
    topElement->prevElement = tempAdr;
    NumberOfElements++;
}
```

It should work.

Comment: You're right. I've changed my push() method with yours, and it worked fine. Thank's so much!